# How to Bind two different EVENT to one ListCtrl in wxpython without confliction?

Tags: python, wxpython

**I want to bind two event to one ListCtrl weight in wxpython.**

**Such as, left click and right click.** The former will refresh the content of somewhere, and the later will create a PopupMenu, which contains something about rename, setting...

How should I do?

I tried `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED`, `wx.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK`. It works!

**But, when I use `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK`, it will also trigger the `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED`**

So, How to do this without confliction? Thank you!

Here is my code!

```
import wx

class ListCtrlLeft(wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, i):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, i, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_HRULES | wx.LC_NO_HEADER | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
        self.parent = parent
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.on_size)

        self.InsertColumn(0, '')
        self.InsertStringItem(0, 'library-one')
        self.InsertStringItem(0, 'library-two')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.on_lib_select)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK, self.on_lib_right_click)

    def on_size(self, event):
        size = self.parent.GetSize()
        self.SetColumnWidth(0, size.x - 5)

    def on_lib_select(self, evt):
        print "Item selected"

    def on_lib_right_click(self, evt):
        print "Item right-clicked"


class Memo(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, i, title, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, i, title=title, size=size)
        self._create_splitter_windows()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def _create_splitter_windows(self):
        horizontal_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1, style=wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE | wx.SP_NOBORDER)
        splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(250)
        vertical_box_left = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel_left = wx.Panel(splitter, -1)
        panel_left_top = wx.Panel(panel_left, -1, size=(-1, 30))
        panel_left_top.SetBackgroundColour('#53728c')
        panel_left_str = wx.StaticText(panel_left_top, -1, 'Libraries', (5, 5))
        panel_left_str.SetForegroundColour('white')

        panel_left_bottom = wx.Panel(panel_left, -1, style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
        vertical_box_left_bottom = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # Here!!!!
        list_1 = ListCtrlLeft(panel_left_bottom, -1)
        # ----------
        vertical_box_left_bottom.Add(list_1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel_left_bottom.SetSizer(vertical_box_left_bottom)

        vertical_box_left.Add(panel_left_top, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        vertical_box_left.Add(panel_left_bottom, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        panel_left.SetSizer(vertical_box_left)

        # right
        vertical_box_right = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel_right = wx.Panel(splitter, -1)
        # ......
        panel_right.SetSizer(vertical_box_right)

        horizontal_box.Add(splitter, -1, wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP, 1)
        self.SetSizer(horizontal_box)
        splitter.SplitVertically(panel_left, panel_right, 250)

    def on_quit(self, evt):
        self.Close()
        evt.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    Memo(None, -1, 'PyMemo', (500, 300))
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What OS are you on? Also which wxPython are you using? You need to include a small runnable example of your code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I think this is happening because the item is selected when you right-click and then the right-click event is fired. This happens with my code as well. Once the item is selected, the right-click event is all that is fired on subsequent right-clicks.

Comment: So, do you have something smart  way to avoid it. I have been blocked here!

Comment: No. It's working as expected. If you select an item with left OR right click, then the select event will fire BEFORE the right click event. There's no workaround that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the LIST_COL_CLICK event to your listcntl and in your event handler.

```
def OnColClick(self, event):
    if event.LeftDown():
        print 'left clicked!'
    elif event.RightDown():
        print 'left clicked!'
```

I did not check if it works but this will be the direction I would take.

Basically I took the strategy for key event handling explained here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/29/wxpython-catching-key-and-char-events/

For other methods of mouse event: http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MouseEvent-class.html

Comment: It doesn't work. [ListCtrl,  Events emitted by this Class](www.wxPython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ListCtrl.html)

Comment: Would you please write a small sample using your method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your issue. I tried on Xubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8.12.1 and on Windows 7 using Python 2.7 and wxPython 3.0.2 and I have no problem binding to `EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK`. It is not firing multiple events. Here is my code:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,100),
                                     style=wx.LC_REPORT
                                     |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                                     )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Subject')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Due')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=125)
        self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.onItemSelected)
        self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK, self.onRightClick)
        self.add_line('')

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_line(self, event):
        line = "Line %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "USA")
        self.index += 1

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onItemSelected(self, event):
        """"""
        print "Item selected"

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onRightClick(self, event):
        """"""
        print "Item right-clicked"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I have posted my code. would you please check it? Thank you!